# Inserting node at beginning in a Linked List in Python

Tags: python, linked-list

> Below is the code for Linked list...we have takeInput() function which takes the input from the user. Also, we have insertAtI() function that is to insert a node anywhere in the linked list. But it's not inserting at the beginning...please have a look...and help me in resolving the issue.

```
 class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


def takeInput():
    inputList = [int(ele) for ele in input().split()]
    head = None
    tail = None
    for ele in inputList:
        newNode = Node(ele)
        if head is None:
            head = newNode
            tail = newNode
        else:
            tail.next = newNode
            tail = newNode  # or tail = tail.next

    return head


def length(head):
    count = 0
    while head is not None:
        head = head.next
        count += 1
    return count


def insertAtI(head, i, data):

    if i < 0 or i > length(head):
        return head

    count = 0
    prev = None
    curr = head

    while count < i:
        prev = curr
        curr = curr.next
        count += 1

    newNode = Node(data)

    if prev is not None:
        prev.next = newNode
    else:
        head = newNode

    newNode.next = curr

    return head


def printLL(head):
    while head is not None:
        print(head.data, end="->")
        head = head.next
    print("None")


head = takeInput()
printLL(head)


insertAtI(head, 1, 7)
insertAtI(head, 4, 9)
insertAtI(head, 0, 2)
printLL(head)
```

> This code is not inserting the node at the beginning of my linked list. I think the problem is inside  insertAtI() function...please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: Your `insertAtI` looks fine to me. You should try adding `breakpoint()` before you call the function and stepping through your code to debug it. Also, in Python, variables and function names should be named using `lowercase_with_underscores` not `camelCase`.

Comment: All you need to do is assign the return value of `insertAtI` to `head`.

Comment: @pppig first two insertions are fine even without assigning, but the third one (i.e. insertAtI(head, 0, 2)) works only when I assign it to some variable. Why is it so ?

Comment: @Abhinavtyagi the code that prints the linked list starts going over the list from whatever argument you pass in. For example, if your list is `1->2->3->4->None` and you do `printLL(head.next.next)` it'll print `3->4->None`. When you `insertAtI(head, 0)`, it creates a new node, but your variable `head` is still pointing to the old head (which is now the second element in the list), so when you pass it to `printLL(head)` it's not starting from the new head element you created with `insertAtI()`. So any time you use `insertAtI` you need to do `head = insertAtI` because it returns the correcthead

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite your `head` variable with whatever head `insertAtI` returns. It will return a new element as the head if you're inserting into the beginning of the list with `insertAtI(head, 0, <whatever>)` or the same head you passed in if you're inserting somewhere else in the list. So instead of

```py
insertAtI(head, 1, 7)
insertAtI(head, 4, 9)
insertAtI(head, 0, 2)
printLL(head)
```

do

```
head = insertAtI(head, 1, 7)
head = insertAtI(head, 4, 9)
head = insertAtI(head, 0, 2)
printLL(head)
```